# Solve $150\sin(2x)+100\cos(2x)=0$ analytically

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

Is there any way we can solve the following function analytically?

$$150\sin(2x)+100\cos(2x)=0$$

Comment: $\tan(2x)=-2/3$

Answer (score 3):

Divide by $50$ first of all

$$3\sin(2x) + 2\cos(2x) = 0$$

Now just divide by $2\sin(2x)$:

$$\frac{3}{2} + \tan(2x) = 0$$

Hence

$$\tan(2x) = -\frac{2}{3}$$

Now

$$2x = \arctan(-2/3)$$

And don't forget the period!